# Meaning of trifling, petty and picayune when describing a person

Tags: meaning, syntactic-analysis

What do **trifling, petty and picayune** mean when describing a person? According to dictionaries I looked at, they all mean worthless and trivial, but then following sentence does not make sense to me. I also found **picayune** has a meaning of "carping or prejudiced", which I still can't fit it into the sentence.

Can someone explain what do they mean exactly in this sentence? As far as I understand the logic of the sentence, the words **picayune** in the sentence should have a meaning similar to "**contrary to the rules**" but I just can't find any definition similar to that.

The sentence:

*English teachers are notorious for being picayune(trifling, petty); however, the English language is so nuanced and sophisticated that often such teachers are not being contrary but are only adhering to the rules.*

Comment: They all have the connotation of small and unimportant. Small-minded is what's intended here.

Comment: Oh thanks, small-minded actually fits perfectly into the sentence! I don't know if native English speakers always treat "unimportant" and "small-minded" as the same thing but I really think this should be put into dictionaries as a non-native speaker..

Comment: "Pettifogger": someone who quibbles over trivia, and raises petty, annoying objections. (Wiktionary).

Comment: I suspect that *picayune* was chosen partly because it's a ten-dollar word that sounds similar to *picky*, and then the definition was sort of stretched-to-fit. Personally, I would *not* say that English teachers are notorious for being picayune, but I *might* say they have a certain reputation for pickiness.

Comment: One implication is that they exude too much angst over trivial issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the sentence used, all of these derogatory adjectives simply mean that one might think an English teacher is worrying too much over the details; putting so much importance on the small things that it seems like they are not being helpful so much as deliberately contrary.

Answer (score 1):

> English teachers are notorious for being picayune(trifling, petty)

I will give you my own personal understanding of these words.

*Picayune* means nitpicky.  *Trifling* means wasting time with unimportant matters (a bit connected with *silly*).  *Petty* means the person begrudges you every little detail of what you did wrong.